# Active Directory Attribute List Using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

How i get the list of active directory user attributes(not of particular user i.e.all attributes) e.g.cn,mail etc. using c#?

Comment: I think you should tag this with "active directory", not asp.net or mvc, since the question doesn't relate to either of them.

Comment: or may be you should add tag ldap

Answer (score 5):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you need to check out the classes in `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` for this. You need to look at classes like [`ActiveDirectorySchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryschema.aspx) and [`ActiveDirectorySchemaClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryschemaclass.aspx).

You can get hold of the current AD schema by using:

```
ActiveDirectorySchema currSchema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();
```

When you have the current schema, you can inspect the various class definitions, e.g.:

```
ActiveDirectorySchemaClass userSchema = currSchema.FindClass("person");
```

Once you have that object, you can inspect and enumerate its properties, things like:

- MandatoryProperties
- OptionalProperties

and so on to get an insight into the AD schema.

Comment: doh, you are 3 seconds faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry();
    dir.Path = "LDAP://YourActiveDirServername ";        
    DirectorySearcher sea = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
    sea.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=Uname)";
    SearchResult seares = sea.FindOne();      
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection prop = seares.Properties;
    ICollection coll = prop.PropertyNames;
    IEnumerator enu = coll.GetEnumerator(); 
        while (enu.MoveNext())
        {
            str.Append(enu.Current + " = " + seares.Properties[enu.Current.ToString()][0] + "\n");
        }
```

Also, take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Comment: That's only going to give you the properties that this user has (e.g. where there is a value set for this user). This does **not** enumerate **all** properties that are defined in the LDAP schema

Comment: This only gets you properties for that user ... not for "all attributes" as the question stated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI:

```
 ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
 ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("root\\directory\\LDAP", "ads_user", objectGetOptions);

 foreach (PropertyData dataObject in managementClass.Properties)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(dataObject.Name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

While ADExplorer does not list all the available attributes, I have found it a great tool for seeing what goes where.

You can download it from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
UserPropertyList = new List<string>();

ActiveDirectorySchema currSchema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();

ICollection Collection = currSchema.FindAllProperties();

IEnumerator Enumerator = Collection.GetEnumerator();

while (Enumerator.MoveNext())
{
   UserPropertyList.Add(Enumerator.Current.ToString());
}
```

The above code will add all search attributes of Active Directory to the `UserPropertyList...`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on **marc_s**'s answer here. Here is a complete code example that prints the common name and the actual attribute name.

```c#
ActiveDirectorySchema schema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();
ActiveDirectorySchemaClass person = schema.FindClass("user");
foreach( ActiveDirectorySchemaProperty property in person.GetAllProperties() )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.CommonName, property.Name);
}
```

Example output.

```
Common-Name = cn
Instance-Type = instanceType
NT-Security-Descriptor = nTSecurityDescriptor
Object-Category = objectCategory
Object-Class = objectClass
Object-Sid = objectSid
SAM-Account-Name = sAMAccountName
Account-Expires = accountExpires
...
```