# List all attributes of a user in AD by C# code

Tags: c#, active-directory

Suppose my windows logon user name is "test". I want to list all attributes such "cn" and "samaccountname" of it etc.

Is that possible with C# code?
Thanks.

Comment: there is a nice feature of StackOverflow, when you enter question title and move focus to question body, you see suggested similar questions, you should have seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335112/active-directory-attribute-list-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace to do what you want. [Codeproject has more information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) on what you can do.