# Searching DirectoryServices to return a list of modified users by date

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

We have a large LDAP directory that we're currently returning all users from. We iterate through the list of users, and compare what we've saved locally to find those that either no-longer exist, or that are new, then create/delete them locally.

The problem is that this operation takes HOURS to complete.

I think the solution to this would be to define a more specific search query to Directory Services and only return those users that have been modified in the last 24 hours (or whenever it last ran). Unfortunately I'm having difficulty finding which property to use in order to make the search query more specific.

I've looked at [this list of available properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but all I can see that might work is 'ms-DFS-Last-Modified-v2', however, I'm not sure how to use it.

Any other ideas?

The code we're using to search currently is below:

```
            PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN", "dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=co,dc=za");
            UserPrincipal theuser = new UserPrincipal(domainContext);

            theuser.Name = "*";

            // create a principal searcher for running a search operation
            PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher(theuser);

            // assign the query filter property for the principal object 
            pS.QueryFilter = theuser;

            // run the query
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> theresults = pS.FindAll();
            retUsers = new List<ActiveDirectoryUser>();
            List<UserPrincipal> copyUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
            copyUsers = theresults.OfType<UserPrincipal>().Where(userresult => userresult.EmailAddress != null).ToList();


            foreach (UserPrincipal result in copyUsers)
            {
               ... process users.
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using these LDAP filter properties:

Modified                             : 7/10/2014 8:35:17 AM

modifyTimeStamp                      : 7/10/2014 8:35:17 AM

Which were found by following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650158/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-properties-to-search-using-ldap-filters).

Comment: -> I have almost similar requirement. This is an old post but can you post some sample as to how to use C# AD queries to retrieve items modified since date? Also, does it also return the deleted items?

Comment: The query is created based on the property filters you want to work with. Something like `dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(PROPERTYNAME=" + VALUE + "))";`. Replace PROPERTYNAME with the actual AD property and then obviously with the value you provide. Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use LDAP filters, and find a few [examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-make-search-in-AD-cb67a9b4) easy enough. I am not sure about the filter syntax for dates though. I would check [documentation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) for that.

**Edit:** You can get the list of attributes by querying the [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryschema.aspx). There aren't many examples in documentation unfortunately. Have a look at [questions about Active Directory attribute listings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335112/active-directory-attribute-list-using-c-sharp) for examples.

Comment: The documentation link you provided doesn't provide any examples of what I need :(

Comment: what about the example? Did you try using DirectorySearcher?

Comment: The more I search for LDAP filter queries the more I realize how terrible the official documentation is.

Comment: Yes, but the DirectorySearcher still uses LDAP search filter queries. The better question at this point may be 'Where can I find a _complete_ list of properties to search using LDAP filters?'

Comment: Don't know a lot about AD specifically but worked with LDAP stuff before. It boils down to the schema you are using. There is a way to extract that as well I think