# Where can I find a complete list of properties to search using LDAP filters?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

As an extension to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649579/searching-directoryservices-to-return-a-list-of-modified-users-by-date) about how to search for users last modified on/before/after a certain date, I realize that the answer may lie in finding a well-documented list of LDAP filter properties to search on.

Does anyone know where I might find a list like this?

I've tried [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx), but it's not complete.

Comment: I think [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026546/get-all-possible-attributes-and-all-objectclasses-from-openldap-in-php) answers how you can get the list from the AD server. This obviously is not documented, but if its just a list you are after, you can do it by following the steps suggested in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to simply look at the attribute list for a user in Active Directory Users and Computers.

To do this you need to:

- Enable Advanced Features (View Menu)
- Bring up properties of a user or any other object
- Select Attribute Editor tab
- Use the filter button to disable "Show only attributes that have values"

You can also use ADSIEdit if you're sure you wont break anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's entirely complete, but the amount of attributes I found here was more than I've seen anywhere else, AND included the Modified attribute that I was after. Thanks